# grub: module ext4dev not found after moving partitions

Tags: partitioning, debian, grub

os: debian testing 64bit

hd:

```
/dev/sda1 20 gig
/dev/sda2 100 mb /boot
/dev/sda3 extended
/dev/sda5 /
```

I deleted sda1 and sda2, created a new sda1 with 100mb and sda2 with 20 gig.
copied the contents of / (sda5) to sda2.

booted into debian live rescue, chrooted sda2 and mounted sda1 to /boot.
i edited my /etc/fstab to match the uuids of / and /boot with sda2 and sda1.
then i did

```
grub-mkdevicemap
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
```

when i reboot now, i get a grub with a menu for my kernels and memtest, etc.

however if i select my default entry grub tries to boot and says

```
module ext4 not found
```

can't find file or director /dev/by-uuid/$UUID

and several other modules not found

EDIT1: unfortunatley sda5 seems not to be ext3 as expected

EDIT2: grub entry

```
os {
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root $UUID_OF_SDA1
    echo    '…'
    linux   /vmlinuz-3.2.0-2-amd64 root=UUID=$UUID_OF_SDA2 ro  quiet
    echo    '...'
    initrd  /initrd.img-3.2.0-2-amd64
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Was your / on /dev/sda5 also an ext4 partition?
2. What is your default grub entry?

I see tow possibilities:
a) your default grub entry is a chainload command to /dev/sda2 and you don't have grub installed on /dev/sda2.
b) This error message is not generated by Grub but by your kernel and it doesn't have ext4 support and you have to rebuild your ramdisk to include an ext4 driver.

Comment: 1. it should have but it seems to be ext3, at least debian rescue mounts it as such. 2. i edit the default entry in my question

Comment: Well then b) is the answer to your problem ...

Comment: dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-3.2.0-2-amd64 in the chrooted shell did the trick. thank you